# MediaWiki Googlelogin shows tag <googlelogin> instead of lable "Login with Google"

Tags: php, mediawiki

While I'm signing in with Google account I see HTML tag on buttons instead of Lables.

How can I fix it?

I found a `.json` file with `tag-lable` mapping:

```
ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01:/var/www/html/extensions$ sudo grep -r 
    "googlelogin-form-choosename-title" 
    GoogleLogin/ GoogleLogin/includes/specials/SpecialGoogleLogin.php: 
    $out->setPageTitle( 
        $this->msg( 'googlelogin-form-choosename-title' )->text() ); 
    GoogleLogin/i18n/en.json: "googlelogin-form-choosename-title": 
    "Choose username", ...
```

How to enable it for English Language?

Answer (score 0):

so, the issue was with PHP version.
I've downgraded from 7.0 to 5.6 and now GoogleLogin works fine and lables are shown on all the buttons.
Be aware)